# Breeze JS: Wildcard in Where

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze

Is it possible to somehow use wildcard characters (`*` or `?`) in breeze queries?

For example: I have a Search-Input-Field where I want people to be able to enter these characters so they can search for german names that have umlauts. Example `M*ller` for `Müller` or `Mueller` or `Muller`.

I already tried `%` since I hoped that the where-predicate (`contains`) would get translated to an SQL-`LIKE`-Statement.

The next thing I would do if nothing helps is to split the string and create different where-predicates that are and/or connected but I'm still hoping for a better solution.